# Handling Spring Cloud Config Remote Refresh Event Failures

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-gateway

I've built up a Spring Cloud Config Server integrated using Spring Cloud Bus via Kafka for refreshing properties dynamically. I've another application that is Spring Cloud Gateway that consumes those properties and refreshes them dynamically.

One of the things I'm struggling with is if I (unintentionally) update a bad property (for example: `spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/demo/{demoId\:[0-9]+}`, here backslash is something that is wrong here) in a Spring Gateway route. 
The routing breaks in Spring Cloud Gateway with the error something like unable to initialize bean `GatewayProperties` and things starts behaving weirdly.

Two questions:

1. Is there a way to ignore bad config refresh events? Probably skipping refresh event that has a bad config.
2. If it's possible, Is there a way to evaluate those properties even before those are applied to the Spring context?

Comment: Right now, it's not possible to know the property is bad until after it is loaded into the environment after the refresh event.

Comment: Ah. Is there any workaround? Anything I can customize, extend, override, etc. Is this something it is being worked on? If yes, can you please share tentative release train?

Comment: Not currently. You really should be either canrarying config or putting it thru some process before it hits production.